# VBA（Excel）の処理速度について

Tags: vba, excel

logファイル（7～8万行程度）を読み込み、A列に空白があった場合に、
その列を削除する処理ですが、この処理だけでも
3～5分程度かかってしまいます。
Excelの処理では、7～8万行の処理では、このぐらいの時間がかかって
しまうものなのでしょうか？

PCのスペックは、Win10pro core i7 メモリ16GBです。

```
Sub test()
    Dim txtPath As String
    Dim TmpMaxRow As Long
    
    txtPath = "C:\sample.log"
    
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=txtPath, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Tab:=True, _
        Space:=True
    
'A列に空白行があった場合は、その列を削除
    TmpMaxRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:A" & TmpMaxRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
end sub
```

Comment: 処理中のCPU使用率、メモリ消費量はどうでしたか？ マクロの他に重いアプリを使用していたりなどの影響も受けるかと思います。Excel自体軽くはないと思うので、PowerShell等で処理した方が速い場合が多いかとは思います。

Comment: 似たような状況に見えるこんな記事が参考になるかも。[VBAで、大量データ（8万行くらいです。。）の中からE列に特定のデータがある場合行削除を行いたいのですが](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10185406235)

Answer (score 1):

Excelのセルの操作はCPUとメモリへの負荷が大きいオペレーションですので、どうしても重くなりがちです。小手先のテクニックとしては「再計算を手動にする」「画面の再描画をオフにする」などがありますが、効果は限られます。本質的な解決としては、Excelのセルにデータを書き出す前に、不要な行の削除などできる限りの処理を行っておくべきです。

方法としては、たとえばADOでテキストファイルをSQLテーブルとして扱い、クエリ処理する方法があります。私の環境（Core i5 / 16GB）で10万行を読み込むのに1～2秒です。

```
Dim Conn As Object
Dim Command As Object
Dim Recordset As Object
    
Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Provider = "Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0"
Conn.Properties("Data Source") = "C:"
Conn.Properties("Extended Properties") = "Text;"
Conn.Open
    
Set Command = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Command.ActiveConnection = Conn
Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [sample.log] WHERE NOT IsNull(F1)"
    
Set Recordset = Command.Execute()
    
Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset Recordset
```

なお細かい補足になりますが、この方法でタブ区切りファイルを扱う場合は、schema.iniというファイルを元データと同じフォルダ内に作成する必要があります。以下が内容の例ですが、詳細はMicrosoftのドキュメントにてご確認ください。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-ver16

```
[sample.log]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=TabDelimited
Col1=F1 Text
Col2=F2 Text
```